# Strangely For loop counter variable gets reduced by .get()

Tags: c++, for-loop, get

Consider the following piece of code. This function reads the some integers and strings from a file.

```
const int vardo_ilgis = 10;
void skaityti(int &n, int &m, int &tiriama, avys A[])
{
    ifstream fd("test.txt");
    fd >> n >> m >> tiriama;
    fd.ignore(80, '\n');
    char vard[vardo_ilgis]; // <---
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << i << ' ';
        fd.get(vard, vardo_ilgis+1); // <---
        cout << i << endl;
        A[i].vardas = vard;
        getline(fd, A[i].DNR);
    }
    fd.close();
}
```

and input:

```
4 6
4
Baltukas   TAGCTT
Bailioji   ATGCAA
Doli       AGGCTC
Smarkuolis AATGAA
```

In this case, variable 'vard' has a length vardo_ilgis = 10, but in function fd.get the read input is vardo_ilgis+1 = 11 (larger than the variable length in which data is stored). I'm not asking how to fix a problem, because it's obvious not to read more than you can store on a variable. 
However, I really want to understand the reason of this behaviour: the loop count variable gets decreased by fd.get. Why and how even can this happen? That's the output of this little piece of code:

```
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

Comment: which language is this? sounds like high Valyrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you use `+1` ??

```
fd.get(vard, vardo_ilgis+1);
```

Overrunning that buffer corrupts some memory.  In a simple unoptimized build, that corrupted memory could be the loop index.

> the loop count variable gets decreased by fd.get. Why and how even can this happen?

Once you know why you have caused undefined behavior, many people say you aren't supposed to inquire into the details of that undefined behavior.  I disagree.  By understanding the details, you can improve your ability to diagnose other situations where you don't know what undefined behavior you might have invoked.

All you local variables are stored together, so overwriting one will tend to clobber another.

You describe the variable being "decreased" when in fact it was set to zero.  The fact that it was 1 before being zeroed didn't affect its being zeroed.  The undefined behavior happened to be equivalent to `i&=~255;` which for values under 256 is equal to `i=0;`.  It is more accidental that you could see it as `i--;`

Hopefully it is clear why `i` stopped being zeroed once you ran out of input.

Answer (score 0):

`fd.get(vard, vardo_ilgis+1);` makes buffer be written out-of-bounds.

In your case, the area where you write (and where you should not) is probably the same memory area where `i` is stored.

But, what's most important is that you end up with the so famous undetermined behaviour. Which mean anything could happen and there is no point trying to understand why or how (what happens is platform, compiler and even context specific, I don't think anyone can predict nor explain it).